# clip the image to the border of the bar chart bars in Core Plot CPTBarPlot

Tags: ios, core-plot, bar-chart

In my code images used instead of data labels using CPTPlotSpaceAnnotaions to display in center in the each bars of the bar plot. The images placed at the center and working fine, but if the image is enlarged it is stretched outside of the bar. I need it to cut off upto the bar width.

Image is drawn using,

```
CPTBorderedLayer *borderedLayerObject =[[CPTBorderedLayer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 52, 52)];
borderedLayerObject.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:cptimage];

NSArray *anchorPoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:xPosition, yPosition, nil];
CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *imageAnnotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc]initWithPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace anchorPlotPoint:anchorPoint];
imageAnnotation.contentLayer = borderedLayerObject;
[graph.plotAreaFrame addAnnotation:imageAnnotation];
return imageAnnotation;
```

and this borderedLayerObject is set as the contentLayer of CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation, and CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation object is returned...

the image i draw take the frame size of borderedLayerObject and its placed over the bar in the barplot, so i'm unable to understand how to crop the image i've drawn...

CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation is used becoz i need to display the image at the center of the bar plot, using anchorpoint i've given the x and y position that where the images must be displayed in the bar of barplot. Please help me to get the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to determine the width of the bars. If `barWidthsAreInViewCoordinates` is `YES`, the width is given by the `barWidth` property. Otherwise, you have to use the plot space to convert data coordinates to pixels. Pick two points that are `barWidth` units apart along the axis that is perpendicular to the bars (e.g., the x-axis for vertical bars), convert them both to view coordinates with the plot space, and find the width from the converted points.

Comment: in my code barWidthAreInViewCoordinate is NO, but am using barWidth property to set the bar width.. here how i pick two points of bar width? please help me to know about this...

Comment: if bar width is the problem and if i set the bar width as image size, wont the original image size get affected??? i actually need to display the images with its original size inside the bars which does'nt streach outside and the image must get cropped along with the barwidth border...

Comment: For example, if you have vertical bars, convert (0, 0) and (`barWidth`, 0) to view coordinates. The difference in the x-coordinates of the converted points gives you the width in pixels (@1x). Use this to determine the size of the annotation. How to crop the image depends on how you're displaying it and is probably best asked in a separate question.

Comment: I have edited my question, hope u can better understand my question....thank you for your support

Comment: Use the bar width to set the width of the `borderedLayerObject`. If the bar width is greater than the natural size of your image, use the width of the image, otherwise use the bar width. Set `tiled` = `YES` on your fill image (`cptimage`) so it doesn't stretch to fill the annotation layer.

Comment: Yes, got it, thank you so much for your help, but now a struck with the new issue, CPTImage displays the image, where only the left bottom of the image is visible and the remaining part is hidden as i needed...Here i need to display the image's center part inside the annotation layer, `slices` = `CPTSliceMiddle ` is not working

Comment: please help me, its urgent, how to make the image visible at the center of the annotation layer, currently the `tiled = yes` is set and the left bottom of the image only is visible, remaining parts are croped, i need the `cptimage` to be visible in center

Comment: You'll probably need two layers for this. Make the `contentLayer` the width of the bar. Give it a sublayer that is sized to fit the image at its natural size and anchor it in the center. Set `masksToBounds = YES` on the  `contentLayer` to clip the image layer if it is too big.

Comment: how to set anchor in center, the image is big and it is clipped because of `masksToBounds = YES` but still am not getting the center anchor point....

Comment: On the second layer (the one with the image fill), set its `anchorPoint` to (0.5, 0.5) and its `position` to the center of the parent layer (the `contentLayer`).

Comment: @ Eric Skroch 'CPTBorderedLayer *imageLayer = [[CPTBorderedLayer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 43.5, 43.5)];UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.jpg"]; CPTBorderedLayer *innerImage = [[CPTBorderedLayer alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];CPTImage *bgicon = [CPTImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale];innerImage.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);CGPoint center=CGPointMake([imageLayer bounds].size.width / 2, [imageLayer bounds].size.height / 2);innerImage.position = center;innerImage.masksToBounds = YES;'

Comment: i've added innerImage as sublayer for imageLayer, and its not working, only the left corner of the image is displayed if the image is larger than the bar width which is 43.5, what i've done went anything wrong?

Comment: Did you set the image `fill` on `innerImage`? You also need `imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;` to clip the image.

Comment: Yes, i have done both codes as you said, i'm getting the image clipped, its perfect, but the image part visible is the "left bottom" of the image, i need to view the center part by hiding / cliping other four sides....

Comment: This comment thread is getting really long and it's hard to tell what you've tried and where you are now. Please update the question with the current state of your layer code.